# EJS template expansion when a string variable getting expanded has <%= %>

Tags: yeoman, ejs, yeoman-generator

Below is EJS code where I have problem expanding 'myTemplate' variable:

```
<% for(var i = 0 ; i < largeObject.elementArray.length; ++i) {%>
    <%-largeObject.elementArray[i].myTemplate%>
<%}%>
```

'myTemplate' string examples below:

```
largeObject.elementArray[i].myTemplate = '<%=largeObject.elementArray[i].variable_1 + largeObject.elementArray[i].variable_7 + largeObject.elementArray[i].variable_12%>'
```

or

```
largeObject.elementArray[i].myTemplate = '<%=largeObject.elementArray[i].variable_1 + largeObject.elementArray[i].variable_5 + largeObject.elementArray[i].variable_14%>'
```

This is since 'myTemplate' variable derivation is fairly complex and hence is a pre-calculated string - but then how do I expand 'myTemplate' string now.

My EJS knowledge is basic - I might be missing some technical correct terms explaining this problem.

Comment: Its not the duplicate of the above as I dont see EJS expansion issue there. Reframed heading of this post to make it clear.

Comment: @npm — Try providing a [mcve]

Comment: @quentin - added couple of examples for clarity.

Comment: Please provide the code you have right now, and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whilst calculating 'myTemplate' variable - I had to do ejs.render(template,data).

```
largeObject.elementArray[i].myTemplate = ejs.render(complex_template,dataObject)
```

Then assign the 'myTemplate' in the for loop as is.

Below is EJS code where I have problem expanding 'myTemplate' variable:

```
<% for(var i = 0 ; i < largeObject.elementArray.length; ++i) {%>
    <%-largeObject.elementArray[i].myTemplate%>
<%}%>
```